# In XAML, How to Make the Popup Control Height a Percentage of the Main Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I saw other answers that deal with grids and suggest "2*", but this expression does not work in this case. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind to window.ActualHeight, and use a converter (DivideByTwoConverter, or something more general like MultiplicationConverter which takes a parameter)

```
public class DoubleMultiplyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is double)) return null;

        double multiplier = 1;
        double.TryParse(parameter as string, out multiplier);
        return ((double)value) * multiplier;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Not needed
        return null;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="window">
 <Popup Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=window, Converter=...}" />
</Window>
```